# Regular Expression in Javascript to delimit words

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to convert a text entered in a textarea, to a form like:

> word1|word2|word3|word4|word5

How can i do this?

Comment: How will the entered text look like? For splitting you don't need a regular expression. Just `var words = yourstring.split('|');`

Comment: in textarea there will be spaces, non alphanumeric characters, tabs, line breaks etc. i need to remove all of these and get this: "word1|word2|word3|word4|word5"

Comment: So for example, the entered text "Hello, my name is Anders!" should be transformed into "Hello|my|name|is|Anders"? Or are you actually asking for how to get an array of words, with other non-word characters stripped out, from an arbitrary string (never mind the |-signs)?

Comment: both true, i need an array of words actually. But i know how to do it with split() so word1|word2 is fine too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
input = textarea.value.
    replace(/\b/g, '|'). // Replace word boundaries with '|'
    replace(/\s|[^a-zA-Z0-9\|]/g, ''). // Remove all non-alphanumeric chars
    replace(/\|{2,}/g, '|'). // Replace repetitions of '|' (like '||') with '|'
    replace(/^\||\|$/g, ''); // Remove extra '|' chars
array = input.split('|');
```

Comment: I still want to make love to this answer!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the user enters the text into the textarea like this:

```
word1|word2|word3|word4|word5
```

and you store that in variable string `userText`, then use:

```
var textArray = userText.split('|');
```

Comment: i am asking for the code to convert the text the user entered to this: "word1|word2|word3|word4|word5" i will need to change any non alphanumerical characters, spaces, tabs etc to a "|".

Answer (score 1):

This should get rid of the tabs, spaces, etc (any unwanted whitespace), and replace them with a '|' character. And, the second replace will get rid of the non-alphanumeric and '|' characters. Then, you can split the text on the '|' to give you an array of the words.

```
var textIn= document.getElementById("myTextArea");
textIn.value = (textIn.value).replace(/\s+/g,'|').replace(/[^\w|]/g, '');
var textArr = textIn.value.split('|');
```

Also, if you don't want to actually replace the text in the `textarea`, you can store it to a `var` instead on the 2nd line of code.

Comment: ... but what about punctuators (dots, commas, exclamation marks, etc.). They should be removed, also. And what about splitting on the "|" character? There are no such characters in the source text.

Comment: Thanks, This is useful, but i will also need to remove dot, comma, question mark etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
var textAreaWords=textAreaNode.value.replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'').replace(/\s+/g,'|').split('|');
```

This will only keep the A-Za-z0-9_ characters as part of the first replace.  The second replace turns all spaces/newlines/tabs into pipe characters. It will also convert multiple consecutive spaces into 1 pipe.

Comment: This will only match the first occurrence of `[^\w]` and `\s+` and doesn't work over newlines. (No `|` is inserted)

Comment: I was writing the code from memory and it was untested.  I have updated the code above to include the g attribute to make it a global search.  After the changes, it is working in Firefox for Strings with multiple new line characters and multiple occurrences of "special characters"